# Is use of the word "dwarfism" considered offensive?

Tags: political-correctness, disability-sensitive

[Ellie Simmonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellie_Simmonds), 4ft tall, is a British national treasure. In 2008, she captured the nation's heart when at the Beijing Paralympics she won two gold medals in the pool, at the age of 13. She has since won several more, gold, silver and bronze, in London and now in Rio. At the London games there was a wonderful moment when the Prime Minister, David Cameron (over 6ft tall) had to bend almost double to kiss her on both cheeks when he presented her with one of her medals.

Ellie suffers from ***achondroplasia***, *an inherited condition in which the growth of long bones by ossification of cartilage is retarded, resulting in very short limbs and sometimes a face which is small in relation to the skull* (Oxford Dictionary Online)

The dictionary entry does not refer to *dwarfism* at all, and nor does the Wiki entry on Ellie Simmonds. But *achondroplasia* is such a mouthful of a word, and very few people know what it means, that it seems better to say she suffers from *dwarfism*.

Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: There are more than a dozen causes for short stature (dwarfism) and achondroplasia is one of them. It's the kind of dwarfism where all four limbs are very short.  Dwarfism can also be present in an individual who has all four limbs proportional to their trunk. That said, I believe the British Prime Minister just wanted to use the more specific and scientific term. The term "dwarfism" was in use through the 1970's and 80's in medical books but seems to have been replaced by "short stature".  That's what we see these days. Is "dwarfism offensive", I don't know. That's why this is only a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of the word *dwarfism* being considered offensive or objectionable, in and of itself. For example, WebMD has an article on "[dwarfism](http://www.webmd.com/children/dwarfism-causes-treatments#1)" and it mentions that the term is officially used by an advocacy group, "Little People of America." When it comes to people with widely recognized medical conditions like achondroplasia, *dwarfism* seems like it would definitely fit and be appropriate. Aside from being more easily understood, in my opinion it's also useful to have a word that covers the general condition without specifying the cause (achondroplasia is only one type of dwarfism).

As far as I can tell, the term *dwarf* to describe an individual with dwarfism is also not considered offensive in general, although some people might prefer to be described with other terms. There were mixed answers about it on this Quora post: 
"[Are both the terms "dwarf" and "midget" considered offensive?](https://www.quora.com/Are-both-the-terms-dwarf-and-midget-considered-offensive)" The main term that I know of that is definitely advisable to avoid in this area is "midget." I have read that many little people/people with dwarfism consider it extremely offensive (and the Quora answers back that up).

Comment: +1 [The Little People of America site](http://www.lpaonline.org/) use the term "dwarf" e.g., *World Dwarf Games 2017* and [their president](http://news.health.com/2014/08/21/5-things-you-should-never-say-or-do-to-a-little-person/) uses the term *dwarf*.

Comment: @Jim The Oxford Dictionary Online says: *In the sense 'an abnormally small person' **dwarf** is normally considered offensive. However, there are no accepted alternatives in the general language, since terms such as 'a person of restricted growth' have gained little currency*.

Comment: @WS2 - Well ODO may not be current. At my daughter’s school there was a dwarf girl and they sent out a notice to everyone when she arrived that said explicitly that she was to be called a dwarf and not a midget.  YMMV.

Comment: And obviously there’s “*little people*”...

Comment: @Jim *Little people* seems popular in America, but I have noticed one UK site counselling against, and putting it in the category of *midget*. Then again I have seen others actually preferring *midget*. My impression is that in Britain *dwarf* is the preferred term. There is of course the [Dwarf Sports Association](https://www.dsauk.org/) whose patron in chief is none other than Ellie Simmonds. I guess that with schools, like your daughter's, they take advice from the parents of the child.

Comment: Uh… did you guys really not notice that dwarfs and midgets are very different kinds of people sharing, basically, only height?

A midget is a short person but with the same proportions as an ordinary person.

A dwarf is a short person with a roughly ordinary-sized head, perhaps a slightly-undersized torso and clearly shorter-than-ordinary arms and legs.

Calling each by the other's name can very obviously be deeply offensive

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: That's an old-fashioned distinction. "Dwarf" can be used to refer to individuals who are short and proportionate as well as those who are short and disproportionate. "Midget" is pretty likely to be considered offensive no matter who you're describing.

Comment: Sorry I can't give examples of something I don't recognize, and could you perhaps explain roughly when that became "old fashioned"? Was it 30 years ago, or last week, d'you think?

Either way, how d'you suppose medicine in general and anatomy or physiology in particular cope with interchanging two very different conditions that have little, if anything, to do with each other?

Again sorry, and I 'm glad I don't know anyone who'd claim "they all look the same" about those guys.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Sorry, that probably wasn't the clearest way of saying it. People do still use the term "midget" with the meaning you describe, but only informally. It's not part of any official or technical taxonomy of medical conditions. There are different kinds of disproportionate dwarfism, so it's not a matter of only two conditions: the term "dwarfism covers a wide range of possible causes and physical appearances. I don't know that much about it but I'm basing my statements on the linked sources and the following Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarfism

Comment: I confess, I haven’t recently heard the term “midget” and I haven’t recently seen what we used to call a midget, either. Not quite just “a proportionate dwarf”, such people also tended to premature aging.

I can’t say I’ve never heard anyone call “midget” offensive; politically corrects seek offence. Come to that I don’t think I’ve heard “midget” at all or “dwarf” often in 30years? 20, anyway.

If some take offence, they need help. Else, “people of colour” becomes acceptable again, by definition diminishing black and brown and red and yellow people as compared to “normal” whites